# Mink > Zombie.js Can't Start Session

Tags: mink, headless-browser, zombie.js, server-configuration

I am trying to create a Mink Connection With the Zombie Driver But I am Getting an Error. All ports are open and I have tried using my servers IP.

My Code:

```
$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver('127.0.0.1');
$zombieSession = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);
$zombieSession->start();
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Server process has 
been terminated: (127) [sh: node: command not found ]' in /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php:406
Stack trace: #0 /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php(302): 
Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server->checkAvailability() #1 /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/ZombieDriver.php(107): 
Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server->start() #2 /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/vendor/behat/mink/src/Behat/Mink/Session.php(62): 
Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver->start() #3 /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/test.php(114): 
Behat\Mink\Session->start() #4 {main} thrown in /home/runniog5/public_html/subdomains/testing4/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php 
on line 406
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Node installed and it's functional. `Server process has 
been terminated: (127) [sh: node: command not found ]` tells you that shell cannot find node command. To verify you've got it run `node -v` it should print the current installed version.

Comment: I am running v0.10.29 of node.js

Comment: Hmmm… try raising a ticket in the [Behat/MinkZombieDriver](https://github.com/Behat/MinkZombieDriver) repo, you'll have better chances there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ZombieServer doesn't know the path to the binary of your node. To solve this, use this code:

```
$zombieServer = new ZombieServer($host, $port, $pathToYourNodeBinary, $serverPath, $threshold, $pathToYourNodeModules);
$zombieDriver = new ZombieDriver($zombieServer);
$session = new Session($zombieDriver);
$mink = new Mink(array('zombie' => $session));
```

In my case, $pathToYourNodeBinary and $pathToYourNodeModules are:

```
$pathToYourNodeBinary = '/usr/local/bin/node';
$pathToYourNodeModules = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/';
```

You can get to know what are your paths using these commands (in case you are running Mac with OSX):

```
which node
which npm
```

Of course you need to set up the rest of the ZombieServer constructor variables. To get to know the default values just have a look on its implementation in your vendor library or at [github.com](https://github.com/minkphp/MinkZombieDriver/blob/master/src/NodeJS/Server.php#L73)